# Word for someone who puts on too much perfume

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word for someone who puts on too much perfume ? cologne ?

Comment: I'm not recalling anything.

Comment: *over-perfumed*

Comment: I'd go for "awful"

Comment: It is one of the characteristics of a *chav*.

Comment: @rajeschwar il (ou elle) "cocotte" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/cocotter

Comment: @Elian - "Cocotter" would be the perfect response for FLU (*French Language & Usage*). Among some proposed English translations, the best one is "it smells like a perfume factory".

Comment: Colognial? Colognization?

Comment: odoriferous or possibly redolent

Comment: I like the word redolent

Comment: Sickly? Overpowering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say **reeks of perfume**

Which has an appealing literary twist because reeks is usually used to describe bad smells while perfume is supposed to smell good.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest "A man/woman of considerable fragrance".  You won't find it in a phrasebook I believe, but the phrase is commonly completed instead with words like "standing", "stature", "authority", "acumen" and similarly momentous attributes so the combination with "fragrance" works well to insinuate disproportionate use.